# find with pipe to xargs grep is not working on MacOs

Tags: bash, macos, xargs

I have had this issue rarely, but regularly:

issuing following command:

```
find . -iname "*.tex" -print | xargs grep -i string
```

I get this error:

```
-bash:  xargs: Kommando nicht gefunden.
```

Funny enough that I get this error in German language. Also modifying this command is not helping:

```
find . -iname "*.tex" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i string
find . -iname "*.tex" | xargs -0 grep -i string

which xargs
/usr/bin/xargs
```

Any idea, what's going on here?

Thank you in advance

marek

Comment: Consider using `-exec grep -i {} \;`, which deals better with spaces in filenames.

Comment: Is it possible you're holding down a modifier key (shift, option, etc) when you type the pipe character, and still have it down when you type the following space? Depending on your keyboard layout, that might get you non-breaking space, which will look normal but bash will treat as part of the `xargs` command (i.e. the command is actually "`<nbsp>xargs`"). The error message has two spaces between between "-bash:" and "xargs", which would fit with this possibility.

Comment: Wow! This was it, dear Gordon! This is because I am typing too fast with 10 fingers :-) In Future no space anymore after the pipe!!! Also thx to Ulrich; probably I will give up the pipe and use -exec in Future. Don't find the button to mark this answer as "Brilliant Solution" :-)